# Populating a drop-down from Database in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

Hi so basically I am trying to populate a drop-down menu from a database I currently have. This will enable a 'Teacher' to select a 'Student' they input grades for. I am struggling to understand any of the tutorials online due to most of them being for django 1.9 whereas I am using 2.1.

Please if you could help, it would be much appreciated.

Template:

```
<form action="{% url 'subject1_view' %}" method="post">

    {% csrf_token %}

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-2 col-form-label" for="information">Student Name</label>
        <div class="col-10">
            <form method="POST">
                <select class="form-control"  name="student_name" id="information">
                    {% for ?? %}
                        <option value="{{ ?? }}">{{ ?? }}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

URLs:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('teacher_login', views.teacher_login, name='teacher_login'),
    path('t_dashboard', views.t_dashboard, name='t_dashboard'),
    path('subject1_view', views.subject1_view, name='subject1_view'),
    path('loguserout', views.loguserout, name='loguserout'),
]
```

Views:

```
def subject1_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        student_name = (request.POST.get('student_name'))
        current_grade = (request.POST.get('current_grade'))
        previous_grade = (request.POST.get('previous_grade'))
        target_grade = (request.POST.get('target_grade'))
        incomplete_homework = (request.POST.get('incomplete_homework'))
        behaviour_rank = (request.POST.get('behaviour_rank'))

        i = Subject1(student_name=student_name, current_grade=current_grade, previous_grade=previous_grade,
                     target_grade=target_grade, incomplete_homework=incomplete_homework, behaviour_rank=behaviour_rank)
        i.save()

        return render(request, 'Teacher/dashboard.html')
    else:
        return render(request, 'Teacher/subject1.html')
```

Models:

```
from django.db import models
from Student.models import Student
# Create your models here.

class Subject1(models.Model):
    student_name = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    current_grade = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    previous_grade = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    target_grade = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    incomplete_homework = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    behaviour_rank = models.CharField(max_length=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.student_name
```

Comment: There is *no difference* in anything relevant to your question between Django 1.9 and Django 2.1. Why do you think any of those tutorials would not work?

Comment: I am just finding it hard to relate it to my situation as i have only recently started using django for Alevels.

Comment: situation as in, I cant relate it to my current program. Also there are not really any clear tutorials out there just people showing the final product.

Comment: Well, maybe you shouldn't have explicitly said that the reason you couldn't use them was because they were for Django 1.9. Nevertheless, to learn about form handling you should start here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial04/

Comment: Is there not a edit u could suggest or something as i am short on time a kinda need a quick fix

Answer (score 2):

Use a Django Form, and populate the choices on the form's init method:

```
class SelectForm(forms.Form):
    student = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['student'].choices= [(student.id, student.name) for student in Student.objects.all()]
```

Template:

```
<form action="{% url 'subject1_view' %}" method="post">

{% csrf_token %}

<div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-2 col-form-label" for="information">Student Name</label>
    <div class="col-10">
    {{ form }}
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Also add add form to context from View.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by add from to context from View.  Also the 'super()' is not being detected by django 2.1